# The CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I have implemented a SQL statement that returns a Boolean value of true is the Username and Date exist in the Table. Below is my implementation. I had also included the current error that is displayed in the Logcat

```
public boolean flagExists(String Username, String Date) {
SQLiteDatabase db = getReadableDatabase();
String selectString = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_FLAGS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_FLAGS_USERNAME + " = '" + Username + " ' " + " AND " + COLUMN_FLAGS_DATE + "= '" + Date + "'";

// Add the String you are searching by here.
// Put it in an array to avoid an unrecognized token error
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectString, new String[]{Username,Date});

boolean hasObject = false;
if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
    hasObject = true;

    //region if you had multiple records to check for, use this region.
    int count = 0;
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        count++;
    }
    //here, count is records found
    Log.d(TAG, String.format("%d records found", count));

    //endregion

}
cursor.close();          // Dont forget to close your cursor
db.close();              //AND your Database!
return hasObject;
```

}

```
rocess: com.example.s210121629.myhealth, PID: 10953
    android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 0 requested, with a size of 0
            at android.database.AbstractCursor.checkPosition(AbstractCursor.java:426)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.checkPosition(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:136)
            at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getDouble(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:86)
            at com.example.s210121629.myhealth.Database.DBHelper.getPerson(DBHelper.java:400)
            at com.example.s210121629.myhealth.dashboard.DashboardActivity.decisionAlgorithm(DashboardActivity.java:347)
            at com.example.s210121629.myhealth.dashboard.DashboardActivity.reloadlist(DashboardActivity.java:327)
            at com.example.s210121629.myhealth.dashboard.DashboardActivity$3.onFinish(DashboardActivity.java:252)
            at android.os.CountDownTimer$1.handleMessage(CountDownTimer.java:118)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectString, new String[]{Username,Date});
```

with

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectString, null);
```

if you want to specify the `selectionArgs` parameter, your `selectString` has to contain a number of `?`s equals to the length of the selectionArgs `String[]`

Comment: I get the following error after making the suggested changes            E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "ANDFlagDate": syntax error
09-08 21:04:25.569  27790-27790/com.example.s210121629.myhealth E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.s210121629.myhealth, PID: 27790
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ANDFlagDate": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Flags WHERE Username = 'tungamiraimujuru@gmail.com'ANDFlagDate= '08-09-2015'

Comment: you have to leave spaces before and after the keyword AND

Comment: I had not included the space

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
String selectString = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_FLAGS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_FLAGS_USERNAME + " = '" + Username + " ' " + " AND " + COLUMN_FLAGS_DATE + "= '" + Date + "'";
```

to

```
String selectString = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_FLAGS + " WHERE " + COLUMN_FLAGS_USERNAME + " = '" + Username + "' " + " AND " + COLUMN_FLAGS_DATE + "= '" + Date + "'";
```

You are adding an extra space to the `Username` variable.

Comment: I get the following error after making the suggested changes            E/SQLiteLog﹕ (1) near "ANDFlagDate": syntax error
09-08 21:04:25.569  27790-27790/com.example.s210121629.myhealth E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.s210121629.myhealth, PID: 27790
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: near "ANDFlagDate": syntax error (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM Flags WHERE Username = 'tungamiraimujuru@gmail.com'ANDFlagDate= '08-09-2015'
            at

Comment: Are you sure you copied and pasted?

Comment: I had left not included a space after and before the AND as suggested by @Blackbelt